# How to use groupBy of underscore.js to group a collection in Backbone.js by a string attribute?

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a model named CartItem:

```
var CartItem = Backbone.Model.extend({

    // Will contain three attributes.
    // These are their default values

    defaults: {
        plucode: 0,
        title: 'cnpdx.cart',
        discount: 100,
        qty: 5,
        price: 100,
        extendcode: 0,
        checked: false,
        salemode: 1,
        comcode: 0,
        publisher: '',
        guide: '3',
        guidename: '现货'
    },

    toggle: function () {
        this.set('checked', !this.get('checked'));
    }
});
```

And a collection model named CartList:

```
var CartList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: CartItem,

    defaults: {
        totalFixPrice: 0,
        totalQty: 0,
        totalDiscountPrice: 0,
        totals: 0,
        checked: false
    },

    getChecked: function () {
        return this.where({checked: true});
    },

    getByComcode: function (comcode) {
        return this.where({comcode: comcode});
    }

    toggle: function () {
        this.set('checked', !this.get('checked'));
        this.model.set('checked', !this.get('checked'));
    }

});
```

and i create a collection with some cartitems:

```
var cartList = new CartList([
    new CartItem({plucode:'123451', title: 'web development',discount:80,qty:5, price: 200,extendcode:'123451',salemode:1,comcode:'7-301',publisher:'北京大学出版社',guide:3,guidename:'现货'}),
    new CartItem({plucode:'123452', title: 'web design', discount:80,qty:5,price: 250,extendcode:'123452',salemode:1,comcode:'7-301',publisher:'北京大学出版社',guide:3,guidename:'现货'}),
    new CartItem({plucode:'123453', title: 'photography', discount:80,qty:5,price: 100,extendcode:'123451,123452',salemode:2,comcode:'7-301',publisher:'北京大学出版社',guide:3,guidename:'现货'}),
    new CartItem({plucode:'123454', title: 'coffee drinking', discount:80,qty:5,price: 10,extendcode:'123451,123452',salemode:2,comcode:'7-301',publisher:'北京大学出版社',guide:3,guidename:'现货'}),
    new CartItem({plucode: '123421', title: 'web development', discount: 80, qty: 5, price: 200, extendcode: '123421', salemode: 1,comcode:'7-302',publisher:'清华大学出版社',guide:3,guidename:'现货'}),
    new CartItem({plucode: '123422', title: 'web design', discount: 80, qty: 5, price: 250, extendcode: '123422', salemode: 1,comcode:'7-302',publisher:'清华大学出版社',guide:3,guidename:'现货'}),
    new CartItem({plucode: '123423', title: 'photography', discount: 80, qty: 5, price: 100, extendcode: '123421,123422', salemode: 2,comcode:'7-302',publisher:'清华大学出版社',guide:3,guidename:'现货'}),
    new CartItem({plucode: '123424', title: 'coffee drinking', discount: 80, qty: 5, price: 10, extendcode: '123421,123422', salemode: 2,comcode:'7-302',publisher:'清华大学出版社',guide:3,guidename:'现货'})
    // Add more here
]);
```

Now,i want group the cartList by 'comcode',so i use the

```
_.groupBy(cartList, 'comcode')
```

but it occurs a error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'comcode' of undefined
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to group by a backbone collection, however the way you are using `_.groupBy()` assumes that you have an array of JSON objects and not in fact a Backbone collection. The `comcode` property is a property of the collection's model attributes. Backbone Collections and Models do not store their attributes as direct properties of the Collection/Model themselves. They are stored in an attributes property and accessed with `get` and `set` functions. Therefore `CartItem.comcode` does not exist and its undefined. To access the `comcode` property of a  model you need to do as follows:

```
var cartitem =new CartItem({plucode:'123451', title: 'web development',discount:80,qty:5, price: 200,extendcode:'123451',salemode:1,comcode:'7-301',publisher:'北京大学出版社',guide:3,guidename:'现货'})

var comcode = cartitem.get("comcode ");
```

So to group by in your case, you can do either:

```
_.groupBy(cartList.models, function (cartitem) {
    cartitem.get("comcode ");
})
```

or even better, since Backbone proxies Underscore's groupBy function:

```
cartList.groupBy(function (cartitem) {
    cartitem.get("comcode ");
})
```

Comment: ,thank u.I use:\r\n [code]_.groupBy(cartList.models, function (cartitem) {
    cartitem.get("comcode ");
})[/code]

Comment: Your welcome. Please feel free to both upvote my answer and also to accept it as the correct answer :)